# Is there a good bootstrap-compatible CSS for admin on Rails App?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, admin

I am developing a business website with Rails 3.2.x.
Bootstrap is used.
The application is intranet style and you may think of it as admin pages.
So no fancy design is needed.

Bootstrap is good for a base. But I want to spice it up design-wise. I checked out Active Admin but it comes with a lot of functions. All I want is just design theme.

Do you have any recommendation for me?

Thank you.

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AdminPlus](http://themeforest.net/item/adminplus-premium-bootstrap-admin-template-/4075896) - Premium Bootstrap Admin Template

Comment: I am trying to load this theme in Rails and i hava an hard time wirking with the assets pipeline. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: https://wrapbootstrap.com/

And here are some free themes: http://bootswatch.com/

Answer (score 2):

[Jarvis Theme](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/jarvis-smart-admin-template-WB09MR0M6) - Cheaper than other templates out there and also uses LESS

Answer (score 0):

I would use [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) + [softwarebrothers_theme](https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/rails_admin_softwarebrothers_theme)